# Giving and Receiving access to a Google App Engine App/Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, remote-access, remoteapi

I want my GAE app's main page to take another app's url, and then have access to it's datastore or some variable it is just holding. I have seen the [article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) and [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) for Remote API. But it requires my app to know the other apps before hand. So is there a way to do this? Let's say security is not a priority.

Comment: if your anohter app's url is also one of your apps, you can write a rest api in another app for anothers app datastore, that can be processes by your main app, but from any other app, this have to be unpossible for security reasons

Comment: Let's say it's not one of my apps, but the app is purpose built to serve up some value, maybe not from the datastore but maybe it's just some 'l = [1,2,3]' I suppose I might have to resort to some form of json trading.